# How to adjust the version of "play-services-measurement-base" with "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release"?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I receive this error:

> ```
> [cordova]  * What went wrong:
> [cordova]  The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.0.0,17.0.0], [17.2.0,17.2.0]], but resolves to 17.2.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
> ```

I install `cordova-plugin-firebase` plugin and read this instructions:

- https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase#google-play-services

> #### Google Play Services Your build may fail if you are installing multiple plugins that use Google Play Services.  This is caused by the
>
> plugins installing different versions of the Google Play Services
>   library.  This can be resolved by installing
>   [cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release).
>
> ...

My `config.xml`:

```
<variable name="PLAY-SERVICES-MEASUREMENT" value="17.2.0" />
<variable name="PLAY-SERVICES-MEASUREMENT-API" value="17.2.0" />
<variable name="PLAY-SERVICES-MEASUREMENT-IMPL" value="17.2.0" />
<variable name="PLAY-SERVICES-MEASUREMENT-SDK" value="17.2.0" />
<variable name="PLAY-SERVICES-MEASUREMENT-SDK-API" value="17.2.0" />
```

After I removed `platform android` and add again, but returns same error:

> ... library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.0.0,17.0.0], [17.2.0,17.2.0]]

I'm not sure, but maybe it's the `cordova-plugin-googleplus` plugin that conflicts with firebase `cordova-plugin-googleplus` because of google services.

Platforms:

- cordova: 8.1.2 (cordova-lib: 8.1.1)
- cordova-android: 7.1.4

Plugins versions:

- cordova-plugin-firebase: 2.0.5
- cordova-plugin-googleplus: 8.0.0
- cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release: 4.0.0

---

**I really don't want** to be required to edit the `platforms/android/project.properties` file (as suggested in most [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The%20library%20com.google.android.gms%3Aplay-services-measurement-base%20is%20being%20requested)), because any installation or reinstallation of plugins I would be required to edit again, and if someone else is going to work on the project this would also complicate.

Can you solve this with *`cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release` plugin* (or other means) and without editing the `platforms/android/project.properties`?

Comment: How where you ablte to install cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release version 4.0.0? If I try that, the plugin keeps telling me min. cordova-android version is 8.0.0. Besides that, I've got the same problem. Maybe you could try to update your cordova-android version?

Comment: @plocks ok, i will try cordova@9 (minimum for cordova-android@8, I'm almost sure) and cordova-android@8... after test i will return with results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same problem for days. I can not adjust the versions. Then today, when I look back to repo's issues page, I saw that some plugin named [cordova-plugin-firebasex](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex) solves this and more issues.

Maybe you can check it out.

Comment: Work fine! Thanks. The biggest advantage is that you don't need `cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release` and `cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release` anymore.

Comment: keep in mind that you also have to update cordova (>=9)